# Definition of a polynomial ring , K[X],K[Y]

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, definition

On the internet I found some definitions of a polynomial ring that I can't really relate to what a polynomial is.

What I find is , DEF : let's say in a field $K$, the polynomial ring $K[X]$ is the set of all "almost all null"(french terminology) sequences. (with sequence coefficients in $K$)
(almost null : The sequence of "$P$ coefficients" , that is zero when the sequence index overpass $\deg(P)$)

The problem to me is that , with this definition , $K[X]=K[Y]$ in term of symbolism , as both are the ***"set of all "almost all null"sequences. (with sequence coefficients in $K$)"***

With that definition , no clear role seem to be given to $X$ and $Y$. Can I have your opinion about this ?

Francis

Comment: Certainly $K[x]\cong K[y]$, but they are not equal as *sets*. $K[x]$ is the set of all "almost null" sequences *in the indeterminate $x$*, and $K[y]$ is the set of all "almost null" sequences *in the indeterminate $y$*.

Comment: I totally agree with you , to me these aren't the same set but they are certainly isomorphic., what i mean is , with the definition that i've written, isn't it obvious that K[X] would be the same set as K[Y] ?

Comment: Just so that you know: the English translation of “corps” is (when speaking of the mathematical object) “field”. And yes, in this notation $X$ is simply the name given to the sequence $u$ with $u_i=0$ if $i \neq 0$ and $u_1=1$, there’s no need to have it play a more significant role. Formally, yes, $k[X]=k[Y]$, but this doesn’t have any interesting consequences, because it’s so easy to build an isomorphic object.

Comment: Under that definition, I think so. But in practice, the most standard definition is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring#Definition_(univariate_case) , which makes a distinction between the indeterminates

Comment: Yeah, $K[X]$ can be written as such sequences, with $X=(0,1,0,0,0,0,\dots).$

Comment: Thanks a lot that's what i wanted to know. And yes the definition in en.wikipedia gives much more sense to me. Thanks again.

Comment: Another definition is "categorical." If $R$ is a commutative ring, and $S$ is a set of variables, then $R[S]$ is a commutative ring with homomorphism $R\to R[S]$ and a function $S\to R[S]$ such that given any other ring $T$ with homomorphism $R\to T$ and function $S\to T$ there is a unique $R[S]\to T$ which makes all maps commutes. This defines $R[S]$ up to isomorphism.

Comment: M.Andrews can you precise ? I know what a homomorphism is , i just don't understand the end of your sentence,

Comment: @FrancisBenjamin Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bourbaki's definition is that the polynomial ring in one indeterminate with coefficients in a commutative ring $R$, is the set $R^{(\mathbf N)}$ of sequences of elements of $R$ with *finite support*, i.e. $\:\operatorname{Supp}\bigl((a_n)\bigr)=\{n\in\mathbf N\mid a_n\ne 0\}$ is a finite set. This set is endowed with a termwise addition and a multiplication defined as
$$\bigl((a_n)\cdot (b_n)\bigr)_k=\sum_{i+j=k}a_ib_j$$
The sequence $(0,1,0,\dots,0,\dots)$ is usually denoted $X$, and it can be shown that
$$X^2=(0,0,1,0,0,\dots), \quad X^3=(0,0,0,1,0,\dots),\quad \text{&c.}$$
As a consequence every polynomial can be written as a finite linear combination of powers of $X$.

Similarly, the polynomial ring in two indeterminates is  the set $\:R^{(\mathbf N\times\mathbf N)}$ of doubly-indexed sequences with finite support and an *ad hoc* addition and multiplication.